# SharePoint List setting doesn't have 'email alert' option

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, permissions, item, sharepoint-permissions

I have created an Issues tracking list on a SharePoint collaboration site and when I assign a name under `Assign To`, the person doesn't receive any notification. While checking under the Advanced setting for the list, I don't have the 'email alert' option. Could someone help me with this please?

Comment: Have you tried Julie's answer? Does it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you are missing this option in SharePoint server?

[image]

If it is true, please go to CA > System settings> Configure Outgoing E-Mail Settings to check that they are set correctly:

[image]

More information about configuring outgoing email for a SharePoint Server farm:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/outgoing-email-configuration?tabs=CASEfarm%2CSEfarm%2CCASEweb%2CSEweb

Comment: If you find any answer helpful to you, please remember to mark it as answer.

Thank you for your understanding.